# Excel - Import sheet from other workbook

Tags: excel, vba, import

I'm stalled, and need some help.
The function i need is to open workbooks through a dialogbox and import a specific sheet into the active workbook.
The below macro work if there is only one sheet, but someone got the idea to add another sheet and then it fails...

How do I change the code so it's only imports a specific named sheet?

```
<pre>
<code>
Sub Files()
Dim openfiles
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sourcewb As Workbook
Dim newName As String
Dim x As Integer

Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

openfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files 
(*.xls;*.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select file(s) for 
import!")

If TypeName(openfiles) = "Boolean" Then
MsgBox "You have to choose a file"
GoTo ExitHandler
End If


With wb
x = 1
While x <= UBound(openfiles)
    Set sourcewb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=openfiles(x))
    newName = sourcewb.Name

For i = 1 To sourcewb.Sheets.Count
    sourcewb.Worksheets(i).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = newName
    Next
    sourcewb.Close
    x = x + 1
Wend
End With

'There is a lot of other code below this

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: When you say "it fails" are you getting an error? Which line of code is producing an error? Or is it simply not doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could not understand question clearly. Tried your code with minor modification for unique worksheet name like `newName & i` and it is importing all the sheets from the selected files. However if you mean to avoid importing empty sheet may use the [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4649-excel-check-if-a-sheet-is-empty.html) to detect empty sheets.

Answer (score 0):

How do I change the code so it's only imports a specific named sheet?

Your code is not testing for sheet names, it just copies all sheets from the `sourcewb` workbook to the destination one.  If you want to copy only sheets with a specified name, you have to check if it exists:

```
For i = 1 To sourcewb.Sheets.Count
    If sourcewb.Worksheets(i).Name = "This is it" Then
        sourcewb.Worksheets(i).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Worksheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = newName
        sourcewb.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If
    x = x + 1
Next
```